# Calling Another Code

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out another way to write this line. Currently, I have it to where if any of the ranges AA2:AA7 = 1 then call code OneLineItem. Issue is, the parameter I need set is if only one of those cells equals 1 and only one other cell to be greater than 1. I.e. AA2 = 1 and AA7=200 (for example). A problem i'm running into is that AA2 = 1, AA3 = 100, AA7 = 200. However I just need one cell to equal 1 and another cell to be >1 and everything else to be 0. If that criteria is met, then call code OneLineItem. Thank You.

```
    If ActiveSheet.Range("AA2") = 1 Or ActiveSheet.Range("AA3") = 1 Or 
    ActiveSheet.Range("AA4") = 1 Or ActiveSheet.Range("AA5") = 1 Or 
    ActiveSheet.Range("AA6") = 1 Or _
    ActiveSheet.Range("AA7") = 1 Then
    Call OneLineItem
    Else
```

Comment: Pedantic terminology comment: what you're calling "code" is in fact a "procedure". You mean to call a *procedure* named `OneLineItem` - I would suggest you omit the `Call` keyword, and rename your procedure so that it starts with a verb and describes what it's doing, for example `RemoveSingleLineItem` ..or whatever. "One line item" just doesn't tell anything about the purpose of that procedure, which means someone looking at that code will need to navigate to that procedure's definition to figure out what it actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 6 numbers so:

- 1 should be 1
- 1 should be greater than 1
- 4 should be 0

so we can use COUNTIF() to find if it follows the pattern

```
Dim OneTrue As Boolean
Dim MoreTrue As Boolean
Dim RestTrue As Boolean

RestTrue = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf([AA2:AA7], 0) = 4 [AA2:AA7].Cells.Count - 2
OneTrue = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf([AA2:AA7], 1) = 1
MoreTrue = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf([AA2:AA7], ">1") = 1

If RestTrue And OneTrue And MoreTrue Then
    Call OneLineItem
End If
```

Another method would be to nest the IF:

```
IF Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf([AA2:AA7], 0) = [AA2:AA7].Cells.Count - 2 Then
    IF Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf([AA2:AA7], 1) = 1 Then
         'we do not need the third, If the others are true then the last must be true.
         'Unless you can have negative numbers.  Then you can add the third.
         Call OneLineItem
    End If
End If
```

The advantage to the second is that it only does the COUNTIFs necessary till it find a False return, then it does not do any more.  while the first does all three no matter what.

Comment: One thing I would suggest is to make the first if statement dependent on the range size. You can use 1 for the second two because its part of the logic and will always be one, but if the set increases from AA:2 to AA:10 the top if shouldnt be for.  I would make that by the size of the range minus two

Comment: @ChristopherMaggiulli That is fair.